# multi-thread QCoreApplication stops before cProfile, PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, pyside6, cprofile

```
def main(argv)->int:
    print("standalone")

    app = QCoreApplication(argv)

    init(app)
    wally.worker_thread.finished.connect(app.quit)
    
    return app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    profile = config.get_def_value(CONFIG.profile)
    
    retval = -1
    print("profiling")
    prof = cProfile.Profile()
    retval = prof.runcall(main, sys.argv)
    prof.dump_stats("pywally.prof")

    print("\nPROFILE:\n")
    prof.strip_dirs()
    prof.sort_stats('cumtime').print_stats(10)
    prof.sort_stats('ncalls').print_stats(10)
    print("\nEND OF PROGRAM:\n")
    sys.exit(retval)
```

What I tried to do here is to run `PySide6`'s `QCoreApplication`, let it finish within `cProfile`, and then get the `cProfile` data. The program ends on `app.exit()` tho, so the output ends at "standalone", nothing later is ever reached. I bet the line `wally.worker_thread.finished.connect(app.quit)` is the culprit, but I need it to exit gracefully...

Comment: If by "program" you mean the script above, then it should quit on `sys.exit()`, not `app.exit()`, unless there's some other `sys.exit()` in your code you're not showing. If it doesn't reach the rest of the script, then the problem is probably elsewhere: the connection shouldn't cause a complete exit, and if it does, then there's something wrong there. Please provide a valid [mre], as right now your code is insufficient to understand where the problem might be.